# Add and remove class to change content of a div?

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I have 10 list elements each of which are associated to different pieces of content.

I want to be able to click on one of the list elements and have a div display the content associated with it.

I only want one peice of content to be displayed at a time.

```
<div class="contentSection">
    <ul class="serviceListContent anchorTag">
        <li class="contentLink step1"><a href="#">Establishing Your Property's Value</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step2"><a href="#">Selecting an Estate Agent</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step3"><a href="#">Preparing Your Property</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step4"><a href="#">Viewings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step5"><a href="#">Negotiation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step6"><a href="#">Agreeing The Sale</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step7"><a href="#">Initiating The Sale Process</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step8"><a href="#">Conveyancing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step9"><a href="#">Finance</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step10"><a href="#">The Chain</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="contentSection">
    <div class="linkContent step1"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step2"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step3"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step4"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step5"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step6"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step7"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step8"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step9"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are your codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the html as it is, you could do something like this

add a custom attribute to your list items with the value of the step classname that you want to show

```
<li class="contentLink step1" data-showstep="step1"><a href="#">Establishing Your Property's Value</a>
```

and then add an event handler to the ul like this that will pull off the value of that custom attribute and then loop through all the linkContent divs and if it has a class name that matches the value of the clicked data-togglestep attribute it will add the "showing" class or it will remove the "showing" class if it doesnt

```
    $('ul.serviceListContent.anchorTag').on('click', 'li.contentLink', function () {
        var step = $(this).data('showstep');

        $('div.linkContent').each(function(){
            var $content = $(this);
            $content.toggleClass('showing', $content.hasClass(step));
        });
    });
```

with this you will also want to make sure your content is hidden by default (or maybe choose only one to be shown)

```
div.linkContent{
    display: none;
}
div.linkContent.showing{
    display: block;
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/silentvexx/q7ajd7ok/2/

Comment: do you see `Jquery` tag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look into jquery accordion. I suspect it's what you're looking for.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/exactly-how-to-create-a-custom-jquery-accordion--net-2690

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
    <div class="contentSection">
    <ul class="serviceListContent anchorTag">
        <li class="contentLink step1"><a href="#">Establishing Your Property's Value</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step2"><a href="#">Selecting an Estate Agent</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step3"><a href="#">Preparing Your Property</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step4"><a href="#">Viewings</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step5"><a href="#">Negotiation</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step6"><a href="#">Agreeing The Sale</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step7"><a href="#">Initiating The Sale Process</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step8"><a href="#">Conveyancing</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step9"><a href="#">Finance</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contentLink step10"><a href="#">The Chain</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="contentSection">
    <div class="linkContent step1"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step2"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step3"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step4"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step5"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step6"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step7"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step8"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step9"></div>
    <div class="linkContent step10"></div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var el = document.querySelectorAll(".contentLink");

        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            el[i].addEventListener('click', eventFunction, false);
        }

        function eventFunction() {

            var subString = this.className.replace("contentLink ", "");
            var divEle = document.querySelector(".linkContent." + subString);
            divEle.innerHTML = this.querySelector("a").text;
        }
    }
</script>
```